# php anonymous functions in php 5

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I've been using callback function like this:

```
private function make_f($arg1, $arg2)
{
    $callback =
        function ($my_var) use ($arg1, $arg2)
        {
            return $my_var  * $arg1 * arg2;
        };
    return $callback;
}
```

[It supports](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) by PHP 5.3.0 but my hosting provider has PHP 5.2.6 so it doesn't work. Is there any way to repair this somehow?

Comment: I don't see where `$my_var` comes from.

Comment: That pretty much depends on what `$arg` is.

Comment: @Dan Lee: `$my_var` will be passed as a parameter when the closure is called in the future.

Comment: PHP 5.0 is seriously ancient (it was released in 2005). You should probably consider a better hosting provider.

Comment: @duskwuff My mistake, it's 5.2.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That really depends on what `$arg` is. For any possible value of `$arg`, I can only come up with something like this:

```
public static $arguments = array();

private function make_f($arg)
{
    $variable_name = uniqid();

    ThisClass::$arguments[$variable_name] = $arg; // Replace ThisClass with the name of the actual class

    $callback = create_function('$my_var', 'return $my_var * ThisClass::$arguments[\'' . $variable_name . '\'];');

    return $callback;
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/o6qwO)

Comment: @webbiedave: How so? I'm pretty sure `uniqid` doesn't depend solely on the clock. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I deleted my comment after re-reading :) This solution works and is pretty much the only way to achieve this < 5.3. @Yekver: Just keep in mind that `create_function` will add a new function in memory everytime `make_f` is called (it won't reuse). So, if you're calling 100's of times in a loop, memory will be eaten. Other than that, this answers the OP's question perfectly. + 1